# Oracle expdp command executed in a command file not honoring %U instead using _U without a sequence

Tags: oracle, expdp

I have generated a bunch of expdp commands and stored them in a .cmd file.  When I execute one of the commands by copy and paste into a command prompt, it works fine.  If I try to execute the whole .cmd file, it also works great.

I need to use PARALLEL and %U, so I have added that to the commands.  Again, I run it manually in the command prompt and it works great and honors the %U by creating multiple .dmp files with a sequence number.  But when executing the whole .cmd file with the PARALLEL and %U, it does not honor the %U and just creates one .dmp file with _U.  How can I fix this so it will create the multiple dmp files?

Here is an example of one of my commands that executes fine when copied and pasted into a command prompt but does not work right when executed as a file.

expdp TEST/PWD@ORCL schemas=TEST directory=EXPORT_DIR parallel=4 REUSE_DUMPFILES=Y dumpfile=TEST_20190906_%U.dmp logfile=TEST_20190906_expdp.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the % sign to stop Windows swallowing it before Oracle gets a chance to see it:

```
... dumpfile=TEST_20190906_%%U.dmp ...
```

As a quick test, in a `.cmd` file:

```
@echo expdp ... dumpfile=TEST_20190906_%U.dmp logfile=TEST_20190906_expdp.log
@echo expdp ... dumpfile=TEST_20190906_%%U.dmp logfile=TEST_20190906_expdp.log
```

then running that from a command prompt shows:

```
expdp ... dumpfile=TEST_20190906_U.dmp logfile=TEST_20190906_expdp.log
expdp ... dumpfile=TEST_20190906_%U.dmp logfile=TEST_20190906_expdp.log
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you!